# PHP mySQL LocalHost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

Up until now I've only used my online server of PHP and MYSQL.
I'm about to go on a 12 hour flight and have a lot of coding I'd like to accomplish.
What do I need to do to use LocalHost?
Do I have to go manually set up a server of some sort in terminal (I'm on a mac osx lion)
How do I set up tables? What would my database default username and password be, or do I have to set that up too? I really know nothing about LocalHost...
Thanks!

Comment: First thing's first: there's no magical technology called "LocalHost". `localhost` is just a hostname that on modern systems tends to refer to the local system; thus what you're really asking us is how to install a webserver, database and PHP interpreter, and that sort of technical support is completely not what we do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't automagically get a database and web server on your computer, you'd have to install them. To install Apache, PHP and MySQL at once, use [xampp for Mac](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) or MAMP as suggested by @TimS..

You then have to transfer your online files and database to your local installation.

This also is the preferred way to work (and don't forget about version control!), since you should definetely not be doing development and testing on the live site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up a MAMP server. MAMP stands for Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP. It's really easy to install and to use. I have it installed on this Mac actually!

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Download MAMP http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html, then start it create database with phpmyadmin default password i think is u:root p:root, put your website code to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ (default MAMP) dir. And access http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a local dev environment, for example MAMP from http://www.mamp.info
2. Copy the source code, database structure and contents to your local machine.
3. Create a MySQL user with the same user and password as you use in your production environment - in that case you won't need to change anything more than the IP address of the MySQL server.